# How can I write a hard drive sector as reserved?

Tags: hex, editing, disk, reserved, sector

I am hex editing a hard disk and I would like to mark some hard drive sectors as reserved so that they are not overwritten by Windows (Vista or 7). I think this is possible, since during a defrag, the disk says that there are some sectors that aren't movable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Unmovable clusters is a different thing. They belong to files the system cannot move for various reasons (e.g. the pagefile).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered marking them as bad blocks within NTFS? This will make Windows bypass them completely.